# Trying to Ingest Data via a webhook call and then push it to store into a Database on Azure - What do you suggest that I do?

Tags: azure

I have my Azure sites that I am going to push data to a webhook on Azure ??? and then I want that solution to push the data to a Database is that possible?

Please direct me to the suggested service that you propose.

The source of the location will be Azure WebApp that sends the webhook based upon errors to this solution.

Just trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure function to push data and write data to SQL database.

I am using Azure function HTTP trigger to write data to SQL database using python model V1

There are two ways you can try :

- **using `Output Binding` of the azure function. For reference check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-output?tabs=isolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python).**

**#My code:**

**`HttpTrigger1/__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import json


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, todoItems: func.Out[func.SqlRow]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger and SQL output binding function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        rows = func.SqlRowList([func.SqlRow.from_dict(req_body)])
    except ValueError:
        pass

    if req_body:
        todoItems.set(rows)
        return func.HttpResponse(
            'Data Processed successfully',
            status_code=201,
            mimetype="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Error accessing request body",
            status_code=400
        )
```

**`HttpTrigger1/function.json`:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
          "post"
      ]
  },
  {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
  },
  {
      "name": "todoItems",
      "type": "sql",
      "direction": "out",
      "commandText": "dbo.todoItems",
      "connectionStringSetting": "SqlConnectionString"
  }
  ]
}
```

**Input:**

```json
{
    "Id":  1,
    "Title": "Sql Output Binding"
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

```
Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-05T04:42:16.051Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=72c3bb48-c244-468c-a9e4-c308d29bc89b)
[2024-02-05T04:42:16.153Z] Python HTTP trigger and SQL output binding function processed a request.
[2024-02-05T04:42:17.075Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
[2024-02-05T04:42:20.059Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=72c3bb48-c244-468c-a9e4-c308d29bc89b, Duration=4035ms)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

- **Using ODBC Driver**

**#My code :**

**`HttpTrigger1/__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pyodbc
import os
from datetime import datetime
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        if not req_body:
            raise ValueError("Request body is empty or not a valid JSON object.")
        
        connection_string = os.getenv("SqlConnectionString")

        with pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            # Define your SQL query to insert data into the database
            sql_query = """
                        INSERT INTO TodoItems (Id, Title)
                        VALUES (?, ?)
                        """

 
            
            values = (req_body['Id'],req_body['Title'])
            cursor.execute(sql_query, values)

            logging.info("Data uploaded successfully")

        return func.HttpResponse("Data uploaded successfully", status_code=201)

    except ValueError as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(str(e), status_code=400)
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        logging.error(f"SQL Error: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse("Internal Server Error", status_code=500)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse("Internal Server Error", status_code=500)
```

**`HttpTrigger1/function.json`:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
          "post"
      ]
  },
  {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
  }
  ]
}
```

**Input :**

```json
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Title": "Sql Client library 'pyodbc'"
    }
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

```
Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-05T05:49:19.655Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
[2024-02-05T05:49:20.895Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=524066d5-ed00-4208-970d-76706e15f6ff)
[2024-02-05T05:49:20.986Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-02-05T05:49:22.552Z] Data uploaded successfully
[2024-02-05T05:49:22.798Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=524066d5-ed00-4208-970d-76706e15f6ff, Duration=1935ms)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]